# GroupBy, Transpose, and flatten rows in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

|  | as_of_date | industry | sector | deal | year | quarter | stage | amount | yield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | NaN | A | 111 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 1 | A | 222 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 2 | A | 333 | 0.3 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 3 | A | 444 | 0.4 |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 4 | A | 555 | 0.5 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | Nan | B | 123 | 0.6 |
| 6 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 1 | B | 234 | 0.7 |
| 7 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 2 | B | 345 | 0.8 |
| 8 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 3 | B | 456 | 0.9 |
| 9 | 2022-01-01 | Mortgage | RMBS | XYZ | 2022 | 4 | B | 567 | 1.0 |

For each group (as_of_date, industry, sector, deal, year, stage), I need to display all the amounts and yields in one line

I have tried this -

```py
df.groupby(['as_of_date', 'industry', 'sector', 'deal', 'year', 'stage'])['amount', 'yield' ].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
```

but this is not working correctly.

Basically, I need this as output rows -

```
2022-01-01   Mortgage   RMBS   XYZ   2022   A   111   222   333   444   555   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5

2022-01-01   Mortgage   RMBS   XYZ   2022   B   123   234   345   456   567   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1.0
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this with Pandas? Thank you

Comment: Is the one line all in one column, rather than individual columns?

Answer (score 0):

does this answer your question?

```
df2 = df.pivot(index=['as_of_date','industry','sector','deal','year', 'stage'], columns=['quarter']).reset_index()
```

to flatten the columns names

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().str.join('_')
df2
```

```
   as_of_date_  industry_ sector_ deal_  year_ stage_  amount_1   amount_2   amount_3   amount_4   amount_NaN   amount_Nan   yield_1   yield_2   yield_3   yield_4   yield_NaN   yield_Nan 
0  2022-01-01   Mortgage    RMBS   XYZ    2022     A       222.0      333.0      444.0      555.0        111.0          NaN       0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5         0.1         NaN
1  2022-01-01   Mortgage    RMBS   XYZ    2022     B       234.0      345.0      456.0      567.0          NaN        123.0       0.7       0.8       0.9       1.0         NaN         0.6
```

Comment: Im not sure how to properly format the result, and can take some advise on it. thanks!

Comment: If you use `pd.to_clipboard(excel=False)` you can then paste it with all the formatting correct.

Comment: Thanks @Rawson!!!  Really appreciate it.  Regards

Comment: @Naveed - thank you! Unfortunately it throws an error in the pivot command -- ValueError: all arrays must be same length

Comment: hi @PeterPan, this should help you narrow down the issues  https://www.statology.org/valueerror-all-arrays-must-be-same-length/

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated by creating a list for each column first, then combined this (using `+`), and turning this into a string, removing the `[`, `]`, `,`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['as_of_date', 'industry', 'sector', 'deal', 'year', 'stage']).apply(
    lambda x: str(list(x['amount']) + list(x['yield']))[1:-1].replace(",", ""))

df1
#Out: 
#as_of_date  industry  sector  deal  year  stage
#2022-01-01  Mortgage  RMBS    XYZ   2022  A        111 222 333 444 555 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
#                                          B        123 234 345 456 567 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great - ultimately need to convert to json, so left the commas in there. And added a reset_index() at the end, so the group_by cols are in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
df.groupby(['as_of_date', 'industry', 'sector', 'deal', 'year', 'stage']).agg(' '.join).reset_index()
```